# Нужно задать разрешение редактирования для первой колонки в JTable

Tags: java, swing

В модели запрещено редактирование ячейки, но нужно задать разрешение редактирования для первой колонки в JTable так как там кнопка должна нажиматься, а остальные должны быть не доступны для изменения. Как нужно это сделать?

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: первая колонка это которая 0? видимо вам надо добавить условие if - думаю его мы сами осилите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так заработало

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if(columnIndex == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```